# HTML CSS, SVG FILL not working, Complete Example and jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, url, svg, fill

I generally try and figure these things out myself, but after a certain amount of hours its good to get another set of eyes. I took my problem and simplified it to a small example:

The Problem is that when the path is loaded in the css the fill does not work. I need .myicon1 to appear blue, but as you can in the example its just missing. I am trying to load the SVG through CSS instead of directly in the HTML, and it works as shown in the third box, but does not work if I try to fill it, as shown in second box it just disappears.

**The second/middle box should be blue like the first box, not disappeared.**

https://jsfiddle.net/xekon/9vcrfs0p/

or if you prefer, here is the code that you can save to testing.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .mysvg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .myicon1 {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><path d="M 10 75 Q 50 10 100 75 T 190 75" fill="#0099ff"/></svg>')
  }
  .myicon2 {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><path d="M 10 75 Q 50 10 100 75 T 190 75"/></svg>')
  }
</style>
</head>
  <body>
    <!-- Created Directly in HTML -->
    <span class="mysvg"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><path d="M 10 75 Q 50 10 100 75 T 190 75" fill="#0099ff"/></svg></span>
    <!-- FILL NOT WORKING, makes SVG disappear -->
    <span class="mysvg myicon1"></span>
    <!-- Same as above but without the FILL -->
    <span class="mysvg myicon2"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: whats your goal?

Comment: will update question, but im trying to get the path fill to work for class myicon1

Comment: The second/middle box should be blue, not disappeared.

Comment: Use encoded svg like this: `%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 200 200'%3E%3Cpath d='M 10 75 Q 50 10 100 75 T 190 75' fill='%230099ff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E` To encode the svg you may use this tool: [URL-encoder for SVG](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs)

Comment: To understand what you are doing please read this: [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris)

Comment: @enxaneta PERFECT! Thank you so much, I bookmarked both pages.